# How to use SwRevealController In landscape mode For only one menu?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, landscape, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SwRevealViewController for side menu. In side menu I have list of menus(Home, Profile, Parameters and etc.). All these menus are Opened in another ViewController in Portrait mode. And I want to open only Parameters menu in landscape mode? I googling Swreveal in landscape mode But didn't find anything. Any idea?  Thanks.